# Pass Autofac container to WPF UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using autofac to resolve Views and ViewModels in a WPF application. IComponentContext is being passed into the View automatically.

An example:

```
    public BusinessAuto(int proposedCoverageId, IComponentContext componentContext)
    {
        DataContext = componentContext.Resolve<BusinessAutoViewModel>(new TypedParameter(typeof(Int32), proposedCoverageId));
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In the XAML for this view there are UserControls being created that have their own ViewModels.  An example:

```
<userControl:AdditionalCoveragesControl Margin="0,10"/>
```

Autofac is not creating the UserControl (the View is) so Autofac cannot inject dependencies into the UserControl's constructor.

**How can I get the reference to IComponentContext into a UserControl that is declared in the initial View's XAML?**

I feel that I either need Autofac to somehow create my UserControl, that I need to revert to the discouraged Global static container (ick), or I have to use a DependencyProperty to pass the container down (also ick).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't inject (what is effectively) your container, as this is an inferior form of inversion of control called Service Locator, with deficiencies that can be summed up by your current situation: you end up needing to inject the container into EVERYTHING.

Instead, you need to approach the problem from the point of view of "What is this component in charge of creating, and what does it need to do it?"

As mentioned by Lonni-Loki, one option is to inject a fully formed control  but I disagree on that point: if the main view has the responsibility of creating this sub component,  then it should create it - but to facilitate that responsibility, you should inject the main view with the services/models/etc it would then need to pass along or otherwise use to create it. Autofac's factory method stubs are ideal for this:

For example  if the sub view needs an IFooViewModel, you can inject the container with a Func<IFooViewModel< (a factory method registered with the context), which it can then use to "feed on demand" the new contained view.

(or a Func<arg1, arg2, etc, IFooViewModel>, as your needs require)

One handy rule of thumb is when considering class X, first take anywhere you "new up" anything and instead pass that into the constructor. Now look at the code and ask yourself "If I wanted an instance of class X, what would I need to pass the constructor?" Those are your dependencies.

Let's take a more hands-on example...say you've got a structure like this:

- Application creates MainWindow
- MainWindow creates SubView1, needs IMainWindowViewModel
- SubView1 needs ISubView1Model, IFooService
- SubView1 creates SubView2
- SubView2 needs ISubView2Model, IBarService

So our ctors would look like:

```
public MainWindow(IMainWindowViewModel viewModel, 
     Func<SubView1> subView1Factory)

public SubView1(ISubView1Model viewModel,
    IFooService fooService,
    Func<IFooService, SubView2> subView2Factory)

public SubView2(
    ISubView2ModelViewModel viewModel, 
    IBarService barService)
```

When setting up your container, you'd have something like so:

(note, I use a variety of IoC containers, so my Autofac syntax might be rusty)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Simple bit, register implementations for viewmodel, services
builder.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>.As<IMainWindowViewModel>();
builder.RegisterType<SubView1Model>.As<ISubView1Model>();
builder.RegisterInstance<FooService>.As<IFooService>();

// ok, lemme see if I can remember expression syntax...

// Simple case: 'static' resolution of subview
// We want a func that takes no args and returns us a fully-initialized
//  SubView1
builder.Register<Func<SubView1>>(context =>
{
    // Since all the bits of a subview1 are registered, simply
    // resolve it and return
    var view = context.Resolve<SubView1>();
    return () => view;
});

// Complicated case - lets say this viewmodel depends
// on foo service, which it uses to determine which 
// bar service to use
builder.Register<Func<IFooService, SubView2>>(context =>
{
    // and our view model
    var vm = context.Resolve<ISubView2ViewModel>();

    return (service) =>
    {
        var barService = new BarService(service);
        return new SubView2(vm, barService);
    };
});
```

The glorious (and in my opinion, only) use for IoC containers is the "You figure out how to get all the bits based on what I've already told you" part - otherwise, you might as well use manual injection, where you pass in dependencies by hand. That said, our potentially complicated construction of MainWindow is now just:

```
container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
```

I hope I didn't make too many typos/errors in the code, but I haven't used Autofac for a while.

Comment: 1. In my case I have a MainWindow controlling the lifetime of the app. That view spawns other views, and on. Are you implying that you would send all dependencies into the MainWindow constructor via Autofac and pass all of them down through multiple view layers as needed?  That sounds messy...  2. Regarding the Factory functionality, I found this: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories but it only makes a 1 line reference to using Func<> delegates.  Do you have a reference I can read up on?  I guess I don't understand the "feed on demand" portion.  Thank you.

Comment: 1. No, you wouldn't inject everything into MainWindow, you inject a factory func that creates the next level of dependencies (i.e. View model, this one contained view). You should only inject into class X what class X would otherwise "new" up. 2. On my phone now, but I'll dig up some material and add it to this answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I wish the Autofac Wiki was this clear. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @kevin-kalitowski no problem! Btw, I just fixed a really stupid typo in the example

Comment: I think something might still be off with the code.  The 'Func<IFooService...' registration is doing a 'return (barService)'. I think those types should match as Func<IFooService,SubView2> says given an IFooService return a SubView2.

Comment: Doh, yeah - should be fixed now; the resolve of the foo service was unnecessary.

Comment: Jer, not sure that your opinion is right. " if the main view has the responsibility of creating this sub component, then it should create it " - it makes sense, but not with visual controls. Also, this king of registrations & View declarations is not easy to read even for the developer. What is the reason for using IoC if it makes more difficulties?) Also, let's imagine that SubView2  will require IBarExService. Then you will need to pass this service to SubView1 and change registration. It's too strange - one control's dependency changed, but we need to add it somewere else too.

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli A class needs to have access to those things it has the responsibility of creating - if SubView2 requires a new service, then the creator of SubView2 will need access to that service in order to create it. It makes no difference if it is injected or not. In this case, if SubView2 needed a IBarExService, you could easily add the IBarExService dependency to the ctor and resolve it in the factory. If SubView1 is not responsible for interacting with IBarExService, it has no need to know about it.

Comment: @JerKimball: anyway you will need to use contentPresenter to place sub windows accordingly. The only difference between our solutions is to use different registration process. With Func<> - and it's only my own opinion - registration seems too complicated. Instead of using one line with view registration, we need at least  5. I've write a little sample with your approach, you may look into - http://www.sendspace.com/file/3kamlx

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli That func bit is a big difference, tho - it grants flexibility. Registering a view gives you a way of injecting a wholly-initialized view; registering a factory method gives you a way of customizing an initialized view depending on your needs. Say that view all of the sudden needs a view model injected as well, but you want to control what goes IN the view model - a factory method that takes the initialization details can be registered and resolved/called on demand, as opposed to "hard coding" a registered instance/template.

Comment: @JerKimball: If I want to conrol what goes INTO, I'll move this component logic to component, not to container. Container is not responsible for that. Othwersise I'll get messy code.

Answer (score 2):

You should not pass componentContext to BusinessAuto view, instead you should pass AdditionalCoveragesControl.

```
public BusinessAuto(int proposedCoverageId, BusinessAutoViewModel vm, AdditionalCoveragesControl view)
{ 
  ...
  DataContext = vm;
  InternalView = view;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding InternalView}" Margin="0,10"/>
```

Then all your views will be independent from Autofac, you should just register all of them in container.

Comment: The <ContentPresenter /> will need to be part of the solution, thank you.