# WPF with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-injection

I have created a Attached Property to `<Window>` with which I can add to a list of objects of type `FooBase`.
It works as it should, but the problem is that I want to link these items to my Dependency injection system (DI). Either every `Foo` is retrieved from the DI or each created `Foo` is add to the DI.

Dependency Injection in [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org)

```
Bind<IFoo1>().To<Foo1>.InSingletonScope();
Bind<IFoo2>().To<Foo2>.InSingletonScope();
Bind<IFoo3>().To<Foo3>.InSingletonScope();
```

XAML

```
<Window ...>
   <xx:Host.Foos>
      <Foo1 ... />
      <Foo2 ... />
      <Foo3 ... />
   </xx:Host.Foos>
   ...
</Window>
```

How I want to be able to do

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
   // The same instance of IFoo1 as in the XAML code.
   public MainWindowViewModel(IFoo1 foo1)
   {}
}
```

Comment: Sorry your queestion is a bit unclear, what error are you getting?  Can you give a better example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I'm unclear, I'm not so good at English. I get no error, it's just that I want to be able to use the objects of FooBase created in XAML in my DI system

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845903/pass-autofac-container-to-wpf-usercontrol